# A language L over an alphabet Σ such that for all homomorphisms h : Σ* → Σ* there exists a string x ∈ L for which |h(x)| ≤ |x|?

Tags: automata

Does there exist a language **L** over an alphabet **Σ** such that for all homomorphisms **h** : **Σ* → Σ*** there exists a string **x ∈** **L** for which |**h**(**x**)| ≤ |**x**|?

Comment: Isn't letterwise duplication a homomorphism? Or did I misinterpret the question (which in my understanding actually does not parse grammatically: what is the predicate following "such that")?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen You are correct, it was a typo. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: Is $\Sigma$ finite and $L$ countable?

Comment: @R.Burton _**Σ**_ is finite, not sure if _**L**_ is countable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, any language containing the empty word $1$, since $h(1) = 1$ by definition of a morphism. Thus $|h(1)| = |1| = 0$.